# How to remove "FILE NAME SUGGESTION" from rendered HTML

Tags: 7, theming

I'm using D7.

I want to remove "FILE NAME SUGGESTION"(please refer to the uploaded image) from pages.

Honestly, I have no idea why it is displayed nor when it was enabled...

So, I searched the ways to enable that IN ORDER TO DISABLE NOW.
I found there are three possible ways to enable it (Sorry if those ways are wrong because of my mis-understanding English):

1. Make `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` in `settings.php`
2. Implement function like

   ```
   function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
     if (isset($vars['node']->type)) {
       $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__' . $vars['node']->type;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Use Theme developer module

About 1, I checked `settings.php` and found `$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;` comment out in that.

About 2, I checked my `template.php` and found I coded the function `mytheme_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {...}`. So, I removed it.

About 3, I installed Theme developer module but it made all pages blank white pages. So I manually updated the module's status from 1 to 0 of the module on system table on the database, and uninstalled.

So, now I don't know why it still output "FILE NAME SUGGESTION". Does anybody have any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the reason why "FILE NAME SUGGESTION" was still output.
It is because a following code still remained in template.php in Zen(not sub theme).

```
$GLOBALS['conf']['theme_debug'] = TRUE;
```

I didn't coded it by myself. So, I guess the code was added when I install some module(probably Theme developer?).

Anyways, when I comment out it,  "FILE NAME SUGGESTION" disappered.